# Javascript "forEach" loop question

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I saw somewhere the code snippet:

```
list.forEach(callback, this);
```

I understand '`forEach`' loop except '`this`' keyword used here, what does '`this`' mean?

if I convert `list.forEach(callback)` to normal for loop, I think it is:

```
for(var n=0; n<list.length; n++){
   callback(list[n]);
}
```

But what does '`this`' means in `forEach(callback, this)` ? With `this`, what need to be added if I convert it to normal for loop like above?

Comment: What context does `list.forEach(callback, this);` appear in? Without knowing this we cannot possibly say what `this` is

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Ok, thank you, I got your answer, 'this' is the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is used as the this object when executing callback.

```
 for(var n=0; n<list.length; n++){
       callback.call(this, list[n]);
    }
```

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach

Comment: But what does 'this' mean in forEach

Comment: @Mellon `this` is just an object in your context. It's optional.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is the current object. The method `list.forEach()` would be called within object context. You should be able to use the snippet by passing the object you want to loop as the second argument, example:

```
var obj = {
    a: "foo",
    b: "bar"
}

list.forEach(callback, obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `forEach` is not standard javascript, but probably was part of a library.  The Dojo Toolkit has a `forEach` construct like that, or it could have been a method added to the `Array()` prototype.

The `this` argument was most likely an identifier of which object should have context for the callback function.  That is, if the callback function itself calls `this`, which object outside the callback function it should refer to.

Comment: It's going to be standard with ES5, and it's already supported by Firefox.

Comment: @Pointy I didn't know that, and I'm happy to hear it!

Comment: The [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach) says that the default value for the context parameter is the global object, which I find a little surprising; I would have thought that it'd use each array element.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `forEach` on arrays that takes a function which takes a single value which is applied to each element in the collection. A practical example of using a forEach loop is the following which parses the url parameters of the web page:

```
var query = location.search.slice(1);    
var result = {}, keyValuePairs = query.split('&');

keyValuePairs.forEach(function(keyValuePair) {
    keyValuePair = keyValuePair.split('=');
    result[keyValuePair[0]] = keyValuePair[1] || '';
});
```

You can then use the `result` object as an associative array or map like structure and get values out of it with `var somevalue = result["somekey"]`